# Launchpad apps in folders limit - OS X

Tags: macos, launchd

I was wondering if there is anyway to remove the Launchpad limit for apps in folders. I'm looking for having one folder for all apps under the same category but Launchpad is limiting me to only 28 apps per folder.

Is there anyway to remove this limitation?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

No, Launchpad is limited to 28 items in a folder. There does not appear to be an implemented method for scrolling a folder in Launchpad.

[Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com) won't allow me to put more than 28 items in a folder either.